# How to change the value of a variable in a function from a different file in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I have two files, say file1 and file2. I want to be able to edit the value of a variable (epoch) from file1 in file2, but it is in the main() function in file1.

**File1.py**

```
def main(): 
  global epoch
  epoch=1
  train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
```

**File2.py**

```
global epoch

var = imageClassifier.main()
epochMenu = Menu(middleFrame)
subEpochMenu = Menu(epochMenu)
epochMenu.add_cascade(label="epoch", menu=subEpochMenu)
subEpochMenu.add_command(Label="1", command=imageClassifier.main(epoch == 
1))
subEpochMenu.add_command(Label="5", command=var.epoch == 5)
```

Please ignore my menu settings, I have been trying to get this bit working firt as it is more important.

Comment: read it from an outsource file. for example, you can write the var value from File2.py into config.json and read config.json in File1.py

Comment: Sorry @EranMoshe, I'm quite new to this and I don't understand - could you please provide some code?

Comment: What about just passing the value as argument ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers naa That'll be too easy... ;>

Comment: What do you mean "access a function within a function" ???

Comment: If I do this, main() will run with the selected parameter, but I only want to change it in file1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Python's FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules):

> ### How do I share global variables across modules?
>
> The canonical way to share information across modules within a single
>   program is to create a special module (often called config or cfg).
>   Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the
>   module then becomes available as a global name. Because there is only
>   one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get
>   reflected everywhere. For example:
>
> config.py:
>
> ```
> x = 0   # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting
> ```
>
> mod.py:
>
> ```
> import config
> config.x = 1
> ```
>
> main.py:
>
> ```
> import config
> import mod
> print(config.x)
> ```

In your case, this means you need to:

1. Create a file `config.py`:

   ```
   epoch = 1
   ```
2. Modify `file1.py`:

   ```
   import config

   def main(): 
       train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, config.epoch)
   ```
3. Modify `file2.py`:

   ```
   import config
   ...
   subEpochMenu.add_command(Label="1", command=imageClassifier.main(config.epoch == 
   1))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I alter this to access the variable from inside a function within the file, rather than just a variable in a file?

Comment: in this example, you can do "config.x =1" from within a function in mod.py

Comment: @YakovDan But if x was in a function in the config.py file, how could you access it in the mod.py file?

Comment: If `config.py` contains a `function()` which defines a global variable `x`, you need to `import config` and call `config.function()`. Then you can access `config.x`.

Comment: user10739557: If `x` was a function, you would access the same way. If you want to _call_ it, just append parentheses: e.g. `config.x()`.

Comment: @MartinFrodl Thanks for you help - could you please provide code? When I have tried this it tells me "name 'epoch' is not defined". Other times I have tried it has run the main method, when I just want to change the value of the variable

Comment: What exactly is this `imageClassifier.main()` function? Is it in fact the `main()` defined in `file1.py`?

Answer (score 0):

One way, is by reading it from an outsource file. `File1.py` can access the file and write into it.

So, under `File1.py` you will have the following:

```
import json

dct = {"epoch": 7}
with open('config.json', 'w') as cf:
    json.dump(dct, cf)
```

And `File2.py` can read from that *.json*.

So, under `File2.py` you will have the following:

```
with open('config.json', 'r') as cf:
    config = json.load(cf)

epoch = config['epoch']
print(epoch)
# 7
```

I think this is the better way to do it as you decouple the modules and having a more maintainable and salable code.